# Cocos2D coordinates clipped?

Tags: ios, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm having some strange experience with Cocos2D.
I can't seem to draw/plot a point at x=0 or y = 0.
I have to move it inside the screen by one coordinate to be visible.
It's like it's cut off or something, I don't really understand.
I want to do some pixel plotting so it's rather important, I'm thinking I might need to use coregraphics instead...

Comment: post your code, please. I had no problems with drawing anything with cocos2d. place your drawing code to the draw method of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D renders 1 pixel at point 0,0 just fine.  There's probably one or two things causing this issue for you:

1. You might be looking at a Retina display.  Cocos2D scales content by 2x by default for Retina displays, so "one pixel" is actually 4 tiny retina pixels.  Telling cocos2d to draw a single pixel at 0,0 on a Retina actually draws pixels at 0,0, -1,0, -1,-1 and 0,-1. (The last three are going to be offscreen.)
2. You may have shifted or scaled your parent `CCNode`(s) in such a way that 0,0 is actually considered offscreen.

I'm guessing its #1. A single pixel in retina is difficult to see so you probably want to stick with the 2x scaling. Just offset your parent `CCNode` by one point for Retina displays which would allow you to start plotting at 0,0 in that local coordinate system without having to worry about any offsets while you plot.

Comment: If @HachiEthan is correct about the assumption that #1 is giving you an issue, make it easier on yourself, and position sprites at points instead of pixels.